# Changing Cell Value upon changing other cell value in excel [Data validation through Apache POI]

Tags: java, excel, apache, validation, apache-poi

I am writing a java class for creating excel data with some data validation in it.
I have one column which shows drop down with some values. On changing the drop down value, it should change the cell value of other column for that row.
e.g.
I have 2 columns Event Name & Event Id.
Event Name column is drop down data showing event names. On changing Event Name, it should change eventId for the respective event name.

Below is the code i have done for making drop down event name:

```
String[] data = new String[] {"Event 1", "Event 2", "Event 3","Event 4" };

CellRangeAddressList addressList =  new CellRangeAddressList(2,dataLength , 7, 7);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dVHelper
            .createExplicitListConstraint(data);
    XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation) dVHelper
            .createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
    validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
    sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

I have a map of event Name and event ID.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set data validation on that other column, using IF...ELSE statement. You can use the createFormulaListConstraint mehod of DataValidationHelper. 
PFB Sample code:

```
CellRangeAddressList addressList =  new CellRangeAddressList(2,dataLength , 7, 7);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dVHelper
            .createFormulaListConstraint("=IF(K3=\"1\",\"2\")");
    XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation) dVHelper
            .createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
    validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
    sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

It works like this: if the value is 1, then the new value in other column will be set as 2.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What is this K3. Is it by default value or cell address of excel?

Comment: Tried it on excel directly. Was working. Will try with Java.Hope it works. Thanks.

Comment: K3 is the name of the column.